# Replicate llvm instructions

Tags: c++11, llvm-ir

I'm trying to replicate instruction (addition binary operation for example), and show them in the LLVM IR, but the following code only returns the 1st instruction (add1) that I built.How to return both built instructions ?

```
        IRBuilder<> builder(op);

        Value *lhs = op->getOperand(0);
        Value *rhs = op->getOperand(1);
        Value *add1 = builder.CreateAdd(lhs, rhs);
        Value *add2 = builder.CreateAdd(lhs, rhs);

        for (auto &U : op->uses()) {
          User *user = U.getUser();  // A User is anything with operands.
          user->setOperand(U.getOperandNo(), add1);
          user->setOperand(U.getOperandNo(), add2);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

Assume an `add` instruction. You have a `BinaryOperator` which has two operands e.g.,: `%op = add i32 10, 32`
You take them as `Value *lhs = op->getOperand(0);` and `Value *rhs = op->getOperand(1);`

So fare so good. Now you are creating two new `add` tnstructions before the actual add since you are construction your `IRBuilder` with op as insertion point.

```
%add1 = add i32 10, 32
%add2 = add i32 10, 32
%op = add i32 10, 32
```

Finally you update the Users of your original instruction e.g., something like another `BinaryOperator`: `%0 = mul i32 %op, %op`

When you look closely on your loop you will see that you set both (add1 and add2) to the same operand of the User. After your loop the multiplication will look like `%0 = mul i32 %add2, %add2`

If you dump the `BasicBlock` where the instructions are inserted directly after insertion, you should see something like:

```
%add1 = add i32 10, 32
%add2 = add i32 10, 32
%op = add i32 10, 32
%0 = mul i32 %add2, %add2
```

But if you run another LLVM Pass that performs dead code elimination (e.g., InstCombine) you will end up with:

```
%add2 = add i32 10, 32
%0 = mul i32 %add2, %add2
```

Because `add1` has no users. You have immediately replaced the uses of `add1` with `add2`. And op is also gone because all users now use `add2` instead of `op`.

From your question it is hard to guess what you have intended with your code but this is why you will see only one of your instructions in the final IR.

Comment: Thank you very much, better use clone() for instructions replication